How to Resolve ESLint Issues with TypeScript Module Augmentation and Merging?
I've encountered a problem with module augmentation and merging. Here's my next-auth.d.ts file for augmentation:
Now, whenever I import "NextAuthOptions," ESLint flags an issue. Although I can disable this check, I would prefer to understand how to properly perform module augmentation and merging.
Both of the following code snippets have issues:
1st
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module 'next-auth' {
    export interface Session {
        user?: User
        expires: string
    }

    export interface User {
        id: number;
        username: string
    }

    export {NextAuthOptions} from "next-auth";
}

The 1st snippet complains that NextAuthOptions is incorrectly typed, whenever I try to import it.
2nd
// import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module 'next-auth' {
    export interface Session {
        user?: User
        expires: string
    }

    export interface User {
        id: number;
        username: string
    }

    export {NextAuthOptions} from "next-auth";
}

The 2nd snippet complains that it doesn't know anything about the default exports ANextAuth, whenever I try to import it.
And I am aware of the limitations regarding default exports in TypeScript module augmentation: Link on ts merging-docs
But Is there a correct way to properly infer types using module augmentation and merging?
I would exptect that the types will be infered properly and linting will not complain using the 1st option.
